# Redirecting to default route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to load a default component for any given route? Lets say for example the only specified route I have is:

```
<Route path="/car/about-you" component={car} />
```

However, a user decides to navigate to /car/about-the-car but this route doesn't exist in my app, is there a way to load the default component i.e.  in this example the car component?

Comment: You can catch all routes with `<Route path="*" component={DefaultComponent}/>`, just place it as last route.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, add a `Route` at the end of your `Switch` component that has `path='*'`

Comment: i'm not sure but does it matter?

Comment: No was just wondering, the `*` is more concise I'll start using it that way

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `Redirect` Component:

```
import { Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
...

<Redirect to="/car/about-you" />
```

it must be added at the end of the `Switch` Component.